# Structure of "the talk was of 'smart' sanctions"

Tags: meaning, prepositions, syntactic-analysis

From an article named "[Iran’s nuclear programme: A red line and a reeling rial](http://www.economist.com/node/21564229)":

> SIX YEARS ago, when America and Europe were putting in place the first raft of measures to press Iran to come clean over its nuclear ambitions, *the talk was of “smart” sanctions*.

Does "The talk was of 'smart' sanctions" mean "It's the talk of the 'smart' sanctions"? It's the first time I have ever seen this turn of phrase. I mean, of course I know "He can be of help" means "He can be helpful", but they are not the same case here, are they? I would like to know more about its structure.

Answer (score 3):

It means that *American and European diplomats wanted to impose "smart" sanctions that would affect the regime rather than the people instead of the heavy-handed blunt sanctions that imposed on Iraq*.

*The talk was of* means "**they were talking about**". It cannot be replaced with "**It's the talk of the 'smart' sanctions**", which doesn't make sense in context.

Answer (score 0):

On the question of structure, you have to remember the multiple meanings of 'of'.  In the sentence

> The talk was of X

the 'of' means 'about, concerning.'

Compare that with this example:

> The treasure was of gold and silver

Here the 'of' refers to the kind of material.

Then you have

> The glory of nature

Here the 'of' is more "possessive", serving to identify that it is nature that has glory as opposed to something else.